# (iphone) pushViewController popViewController retain and release?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, retain

I wonder push/pop viewController on navigation stack would retain/release the viewcontroller.
It's not documented in apple doc.

I saw someone saying push retains. But is it documented or ok to believe that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely does retain on push and release on pop. I would say in this case it simply follows the convention of taking ownership of objects that you need to work with, that's probably why the documentation doesn't mention it explicitly.